# Неактивный элемент в Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

Подскажите, как сделать элемент в виджете Listbox статическим, неактивным. Например, как в Button АТРИБУТ `state [NORMAL, DISABLED]`. Listbox тоже имеет этот атрибут, но что-то никак не получается... :(

Comment: А это QT4 или TKinter?

Comment: Tkinter...

Comment: Я в Tkinter не силен, но может тут вы найдете ответ: [Виджеты (графические объекты) и их свойства. Часть 1. Урок 2](http://younglinux.info/tkinter/widget.php). Вот тут все свойства: [Listbox](http://www.russianlutheran.org/python/life/life.htm#ClassListbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *
l = Listbox(parent)
l.configure(state=DISABLED)
l.configure(state=NORMAL)
```

Или `l.config(state=`

Ну а если надо запретить отдельный элемент списка, то, похоже, увы. В списке допустимых опций для .itemconfigure только четыре цвета: background, foreground, selectbackground, selectforeground.